# Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to ITestContext when trying to set the driver into ITestContext

Tags: java, selenium, testng, extentreports

So I have the following code, which is working as expected, I just don't understand why I need to use the setContext method to set the driver into the context and the answer could be helpful to others as I googled about setting the driver into the context and couldn't find anything.

I'm adding the driver to the context so I can use it later on test failure listener for a screenshot in Extent Reports 3.

Any explanation would be helpful.

```
private static ITestContext context;

/**
 * @param context
 */
@BeforeClass
public void setUp(ITestContext context) {

    setChromeDriverProperty();
    if (driver == null) {
        TestBase.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    if (driver != null) {
        TestBase.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    }
    if (driver != null) {
        TestBase.fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500)).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
    }

    **//So if I use the method below(setContext) everything works as expected** 
    TestBase.context = setContext(context, driver);

    **//But if I want to set the driver into the context like below(I get Type 
    mismatch: cannot convert from void to ITestContext)**
    Can anyone explain why is this the case and how does the below method 
    solve that? I tried to set the setUp method as ITestContext instead of void but that didn't help.**

    TestBase.context = context.setAttribute("driver", driver);

    TestBase.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Reporter.log("====================Application Started====================", true);

}

public static ITestContext setContext(ITestContext context, WebDriver driver) {
    context.setAttribute("driver", driver);

    return context;
}
```

Comment: Because you are trying to assign the result of `setAttribute()` back to the `context` variable, which you are *not* doing in your method.

Comment: But my method setContext does the exact same thing, it's assigning the result of setAttribute to a parameter which then is returned and then assigned to context variable. How is the method working differently that this line TestBase.context = setContext(context, driver);

Comment: No, it doesn't. It calls the method **without assigning it to anything** - because it's a void method, it cannot be assigned. It then returns the given context object. It does not return the result of the assignment, it returns the original context, that was mutated.

Comment: I think I get it now. So basically my method sets the driver in the context, then that context is returned and subsequently passed as a "context with the driver" to the field variable in the setUp method. Basically the confusion came from the fact the setAttrubte is a void method and can't  assign anything to the static field variable context. It's clear now, thanks @RealSkeptic

Comment: @RealSkeptic Another thing I've tried today is to do this TestBase.context.setAttribute("driver", driver); in the setUp() method instead of TestBase.context = context.setAttribute("driver", driver);, but then it throws a NullPointerException because the static field variable context is null at that time. My question is why isn't it throwing a NullPointerException if I run the way it works? E.g. TestBase.context = setContext(context, driver);

Comment: Because you assign in a value. Think of it as "I want a plate with toast and jam". You need to either jam the toast, then put it on the plate, or put it in the plate and the jam it. You try to jam the toast on the plate when there is no toast there, and you'll get a null plate exception.